# Assigning a variable from Wordpress mysql to php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've been struggling with this for 2 hours now. I have a table set up in wordpress called 'licenses', the table looks like

```
license_num| status | user_id   
           |        |     
           |        |     
           |        |
```

I'm trying to assign a variable in php. I have this code so far for wordpress

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT status FROM licenses WHERE license_num = '1'");
$status = $results->status;
```

Nothing is being assigned to my variable. Does anyone have an idea why?

Thank you!

Comment: Try doing a `print_r($results);` to see if you get a query object out of your query. And enable error reporting to see if you have any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use index, because it returns array. get it like this

```
    if (count($results)) {
      $status = $results[0]->status;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `$wpdb->get_results` returns an array of object(s)/array(s). Use `$wpdb->get_row` instead.

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT status FROM licenses WHERE license_num = '1'");
$status = $results->status;
```

As documented [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Row).